# Replacing to: "phone number" with to: variable

Tags: twilio, var, twilio-api

I replaced the phone number in to = " " with a variable and I am getting an HTTP Error message.

```
phoneNumber = +14403943924

message = client.messages.create(
                to= phoneNumber, 
                from_="+14397829146",
                body= message)
```

HTTP Error Your request was:

POST /Accounts/AC5eadecae45ea157bc833c458a3cf0349/Messages.json

Twilio returned the following information:

Unable to create record: The 'To' number 32+14403943924 is not a valid phone number.

Not sure why it adds a 32 in front of my variable above.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm able to use your code above with my own phone number, Twilio number, and Twilio credentials and get a text message back/without getting your error. That being said, something I usually do is I wrap phone numbers in quotation marks--so maybe try changing `phoneNumber = +14403943924` to `phoneNumber = "+14403943924"` (even though I was able to get the code to work without the quotations.)

Let me know if this helps at all!

Comment: Hi! It is still adding a 32 at the beginning of the phone number I want to send to. I even print(phoneNumber) and receive +14403943924... which is accurate. 

When I run with twilio I receive the error above (Unable to create record: The 'To' number 32+14403943924 is not a valid phone number.)

There is nothing in the code that would suggest that the number 32 should appear before my phoneNumber variable. Is this on twilios end?